# Ruby while loop

Tags: ruby

Writing a ruby while loop that take integers as an input and stores them in an array
when a certain integer is entered (-1) the loop should stop and print out the array.
When -1 is entered the loop stops but there is no output.

```
puts " Enter a number"

x = -1.to_i
number = ' '
numbers = []

while number != x
    number = gets.chomp
    numbers.push(number)
  end


puts
numbers.pop
p numbers
```

Comment: _"When -1 is entered the loop stops ..."_ – with the given code, it will just keep looping.

Answer (score 1):

The loop will never stop `gets.chomp` returns a `String` so the loop will go on for ever because:

```
"-1" != -1 
#=> true
```

Try changing this to:

```
while number != x
  number = gets.chomp.to_i
  numbers.push(number)
end
```